# Merge reports in Jaspersoft Studio

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to generate a report with a header, a table with a detail of products and footer. I have one report file with the header and footer it fills with parameters, another report file have a table that show the number of products and its own details from a JSON file (JSON adapter).

This image show the result of each report individually:
[image]

This is my Json Adapter
[image]

This is my code:
JSON file (productos.json)

```
{
 "productList": [{
        "productNumber": 1,
        "modelo": "Bolsa Deportiva Plana",
        "tela": "Tafeta",
        "dimensiones": "40x35",
        "destino": "Bog, D.C",
        "observaciones": "Observacion de Prueba",
        "cantidad": 500,
        "vrUnitario": 1200,
        "subTotal": 600000,
        "iva": 50000,
        "total": 650000
    },
    {
        "productNumber": 2,
        "modelo": "Bolsa Deportiva",
        "tela": "Otra",
        "dimensiones": "50x20",
        "destino": "Bog, D.C",
        "observaciones": "Observacion de Prueba",
        "cantidad": 400,
        "vrUnitario": 900,
        "subTotal": 360000,
        "iva": 40000,
        "total": 400000
    }
 ]
}
```

Header and Footer Report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.10.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.10.0-unknown  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Main" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="8e9538d5-11fe-48f9-b166-d3594b7f64ef">
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="DataAdapterJSON.xml"/>
<parameter name="footer" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="header" class="java.lang.String"/>
<queryString language="JSON">
    <![CDATA[productList]]>
</queryString>
<field name="productNumber" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="productNumber"/>
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[productNumber]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="modelo" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="modelo"/>
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[modelo]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="tela" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="tela"/>
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[tela]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="dimensiones" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="dimensiones"/>
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[dimensiones]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="destino" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="destino"/>
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[destino]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="observaciones" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="observaciones"/>
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[observaciones]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="cantidad" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="cantidad"/>
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[cantidad]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="vrUnitario" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="vrUnitario"/>
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[vrUnitario]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="subTotal" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="subTotal"/>
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[subTotal]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="iva" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="iva"/>
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[iva]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="total" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="total"/>
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[total]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="97" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="47" y="10" width="461" height="50" uuid="a6361980-8b3a-44b7-8b9a-ad381553def5"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{header}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="276" splitType="Stretch"/>
</detail>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="54" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="60" y="10" width="461" height="35" uuid="8c89af56-0386-4fca-a74e-b35e45e0d321"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{footer}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
```

Detail File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.10.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.10.0-unknown  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="subReporte" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="b27ab17e-17bd-45ee-acef-3f80298ad3c4">
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="DataAdapterJSON.xml"/>
<queryString language="JSON">
    <![CDATA[productList]]>
</queryString>
<field name="productNumber" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="productNumber"/>
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[productNumber]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="Field_1" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="modelo" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="modelo"/>
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[modelo]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="tela" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="tela"/>
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[tela]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="dimensiones" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="dimensiones"/>
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[dimensiones]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="destino" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="destino"/>
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[destino]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="observaciones" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="observaciones"/>
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[observaciones]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="cantidad" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="cantidad"/>
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[cantidad]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="vrUnitario" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="vrUnitario"/>
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[vrUnitario]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="subTotal" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="subTotal"/>
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[subTotal]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="iva" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="iva"/>
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[iva]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="total" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="total"/>
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[total]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<detail>
    <band height="300" splitType="Stretch">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement x="10" y="5" width="540" height="40" backcolor="#969696" uuid="cebf9391-ddaa-4354-96fd-ffb4bc640e00"/>
        </rectangle>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="200" y="10" width="250" height="30" uuid="09efa628-d984-4a27-9b9b-9a20cc48650c"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{productNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="100" y="10" width="250" height="30" uuid="873b7396-2256-4781-afa5-a1178f59b70e"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Calibri" size="12"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[PRODUCTO]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="10" y="80" width="120" height="30" uuid="4635c0c8-6106-473c-9554-4deb7905cf63"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{modelo}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="10" y="50" width="120" height="30" uuid="d5c08de2-8bb5-4892-9036-a51306f85717"/>
            <text><![CDATA[modelo]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="130" y="80" width="150" height="30" uuid="6de985ac-4928-435d-b3e0-43c75336e968"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{tela}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="130" y="50" width="150" height="30" uuid="51505f11-5707-43a2-9619-a68b1651517b"/>
            <text><![CDATA[tela]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="280" y="80" width="150" height="30" uuid="92321e84-577d-4aa8-b09c-2aeeae6da75e"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dimensiones}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="280" y="50" width="150" height="30" uuid="7b2273c7-4f77-47c6-bb7c-346dfc3ddf52"/>
            <text><![CDATA[dimensiones]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="430" y="80" width="130" height="30" uuid="df5926a8-a1e0-42af-b6df-975d3e3bfbfe"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{destino}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="430" y="50" width="130" height="30" uuid="43b0ac91-fa58-4c9d-acac-5b3ee37d9f91"/>
            <text><![CDATA[destino]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="110" y="110" width="100" height="30" uuid="a4240e28-ace7-4dcb-a3eb-21c19f6e11a8"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{cantidad}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="10" y="110" width="100" height="30" uuid="2dd51ddf-fc23-47d0-b976-0aa240db016f"/>
            <text><![CDATA[cantidad]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="310" y="110" width="100" height="30" uuid="bf69edd7-d99a-4d03-8c7b-7232a2032194"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{vrUnitario}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="210" y="110" width="100" height="30" uuid="2867b62d-7c49-41d3-8e5a-7b33f8768ffa"/>
            <text><![CDATA[vrUnitario]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="480" y="110" width="80" height="30" uuid="d94d3fb8-91a1-427b-b492-b97698af14eb"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{iva}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="410" y="110" width="70" height="30" uuid="f7352353-b08f-4413-8db6-cc5069dbc920"/>
            <text><![CDATA[iva]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="280" y="140" width="200" height="30" uuid="3b84133c-82c2-4b31-8623-a477d576549e"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{total}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="110" y="140" width="170" height="30" uuid="d4071547-89b4-44e1-8847-3b2c20382846"/>
            <text><![CDATA[total]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</detail>
```

How can i put this files in one report? (the content of the second file in the first one)

Comment: You can use subpreports or jr:table

Comment: i used a subreport element, but when referenced on the main report the subreport shows shows empty